# How to collapse pandas rows for select column values to minimal combinations and map back to original rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

**Context:**

I have a pandas dataframe with 7 columns (taste, color, temperature, texture, shape, age_of_participant, name_of_participant).

Of the 7 columns, taste, color, temperature, texture and shape can have overlapping values across multiple rows (i.e taste could be sour for more than one row)

I'm trying to collapse all the rows into the lowest number of combinations given 
 taste,color,temperature,texture and shape values while ignoring NA's ( in other words, overwriting them). The next part is to map each of these rows to the original rows.

**Mock data set:**

```py
data_set = [
   {'color':'brown', 'age_of_participant':23, 'name_of_participant':'feb'},
   {'taste': 'sour', 'color':'green', 'temperature': 'hot', 'age_of_participant':16,'name_of_participant': 'joe'},
   {'taste': 'sour', 'color':'green', 'texture':'soft', 'age_of_participant':17,'name_of_participant': 'jane'},
   {'color':'green','age_of_participant':18,'name_of_participant': 'jeff'},
   {'taste': 'sweet', 'color':'red', 'age_of_participant':19,'name_of_participant': 'joke'},
   {'taste': 'sweet', 'temperature': 'cold',  'age_of_participant':20,'name_of_participant': 'jolly'},
   {'taste': 'salty', 'color':'purple', 'texture':'soft', 'age_of_participant':21,'name_of_participant': 'jupyter'},
   {'taste': 'salty', 'color':'brown', 'age_of_participant':22,'name_of_participant': 'january'}

]

import pandas as pd
import random

data_set = random.sample(data_set, k=len(data_set))

data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data_set)

print(data_frame)

   age_of_participant   color name_of_participant  taste temperature texture
0                  16   green                 joe   sour         hot     NaN
1                  17   green                jane   sour         NaN    soft
2                  18   green                jeff    NaN         NaN     NaN
3                  19     red                joke  sweet         NaN     NaN
4                  20     NaN               jolly  sweet        cold     NaN
5                  21  purple             jupyter  salty         NaN    soft
6                  22   brown             january  salty         NaN     NaN
```

**What I've attempted:**

```py
# These columns are used to do the grouping since age_of_participant and name_of_participant are unique per row

values_that_can_be_grouped = ['taste', 'color','temperature','texture']

sub_set = data_frame[values_that_can_be_grouped].drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=False)

my_unique_set = sub_set.groupby('taste', as_index=False).first()

print(my_unique_set)


   taste  index  color temperature texture
0             2  green                    
1  salty      6  brown                    
2   sour      1  green                soft
3  sweet      4               cold
```

At this point I'm not quite sure how I can map the rows above to all original rows except for indices 2,6,1,4. I checked [pandas code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.24.2/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py#L1245-L1265) and doesn't look like the other indices are preserved anywhere?

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

```
   age_of_participant   color name_of_participant  taste temperature texture
0                  16   green                 joe   sour         hot    soft
1                  17   green                jane   sour         hot    soft
2                  18   green                jeff   sour         hot    soft
3                  19     red                joke  sweet        cold     NaN
4                  20     red               jolly  sweet        cold     NaN
5                  21  purple             jupyter  salty         NaN    soft
6                  22   brown             january  salty         NaN     NaN
```

Comment: `data_frame.assign(color=data_frame.color.ffill()).groupby('color').apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())`

Answer (score 1):

```
data_frame.assign(color=data_frame.color.ffill()).groupby('color').apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
Out[1089]: 
   age_of_participant   color name_of_participant  taste temperature texture
0                  16   green                 joe   sour         hot    soft
1                  17   green                jane   sour         hot    soft
2                  18   green                jeff   sour         hot    soft
3                  19     red                joke  sweet        cold     NaN
4                  20     red               jolly  sweet        cold     NaN
5                  21  purple             jupyter  salty         NaN    soft
6                  22   brown             january  salty         NaN     NaN
```

Comment: That ffill within assign may cause problem

Comment: @WeNYoBen which problems? Let me know

Comment: You assuming the df is well ordered

Comment: @WeNYoBen I see what you mean: well i guess any modifications will make it same as yours

Comment: What if color has a null entry? and is unsorted? Doesn't work in that case - will update mock data so that it's clear

Answer (score 1):

IIUC I feel using `ffill` and `bfill` for each `taste` and `color`, then `groupby` them is safer here

```
df.taste.fillna(df.groupby('color').taste.apply(lambda x : x.ffill().bfill()),inplace=True)
df.color.fillna(df.groupby('taste').color.apply(lambda x : x.ffill().bfill()),inplace=True)
df=df.groupby(['color','taste']).apply(lambda x : x.ffill().bfill())
df
   age_of_participant   color   ...   temperature texture
0                  16   green   ...           hot    soft
1                  17   green   ...           hot    soft
2                  18   green   ...           hot    soft
3                  19     red   ...          cold     NaN
4                  20     red   ...          cold     NaN
5                  21  purple   ...           NaN    soft
6                  22   brown   ...           NaN     NaN
[7 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: for taking into consideration color and taste +1

Comment: Is this valid if the data is not sorted? Also, color could be null